# Write data retrieved from an API using JavaScript to host server

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest, form-data

Edit: Update - Solution

So I have achieved what I needed to do: Write data to file on the server.  I am not exactly sure how things work but it seems that:

```
xhttp.send(data);
```

does not send all the data in a FormData variable but rather only the data with the "key" "data".  (Sorry if I have the terminology wrong here.)  So what I did is I took my object "userData" and applied the following:

```
userStringData = JSON.stringify(userData);
```

I then put the userStringData into a FormData variable as follows:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , userStringData);
```

This then successfully wrote to the file on the sever.  In the file I only had userStringData and not the "key" "data".

In my PHP file I also included a new line after every write so that each userString data would be on a new line:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "users.txt";
    $file = fopen("./AJG_Data/".$fname, 'a');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
    fclose($file);
```

So this is working for me now.  Thanks to those who offered advice and assistance.

Edit: Update:

Objective: To write data to the server using AJAX and PHP. (Please refer to original question below if necessary)

Thanks to ADyson's comments I have made a lot of progress.  I have learnt that an XMHHttprequest is the way to make an AJAX request to the server.  I have this code:

```
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            let successString = `Thank you ${userData.athlete.firstname} you have successfully granted permission to read your data.`
            document.querySelector("#message-0").innerHTML = successString;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("POST","/path_to_my_php_file/file_write.php", true);
    xhttp.send(data);
}
```

On the server side I have this in my php file:

```
<?php

$dir = 'AJG_Data';

// create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
// owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
if ( !file_exists($dir) ) {
     mkdir ($dir, 0744);
}

file_put_contents ($dir.'/test1.txt', 'Hello File');


if(!empty($_POST['data'])){
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $fname = "users.txt";
    $file = fopen("./AJG_Data/".$fname, 'w');
    fwrite($file, $data);
    fclose($file);
}
?>
```

The directory creation section above is not necessary it was part of my trouble shooting.

The above works perfectly if I send simple FormData created as follows:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("data" , "the_text_you_want_to_save");
```

The problem I have is that when I try to send more complex FormData.  It doesn't work.  It doesn't recognise my FormData and it doesn't get past this if statement:

```
if(!empty($_POST['data']))
```

I have checked my FormData using this code:

```
for (var pair of data.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0]+ ', ' + pair[1]); 
}
```

The above code returns the following:

```
token_type, Bearer
expires_at, 12345678910
expires_in, 1234
refresh_token, 1234567890abcefg...
access_token, 1234567890abcdefg...
athlete[id], 1234567
athlete[username], joe_soap
athelete[resouce_state], 2
athlete[firstname], Joe
...
...
athelete[created_at], 2017,01-03T16:07:37Z
...
...
athlete[profile], https://some.web.address/larg.jpg
```

So as far as I can tell I have good FormData but nothing gets written on the server side.

How can I correct this?

Thank you.

The original question follows below.

I have successfully retrieved data from the Strava API using JavaScript code.  I have the data stored in a variable as a JavaScript object.  I want to write the data to a file on the server.

I have spent hours searching the web and I can't find a solution. It seems this may be possible using ajax or jQuery but I can't find a simple step by step explanation of how to do this.

Bottom line: I want a simple way to write data to file on the server using JavaScript or something related to JavaScript that is quick and easy to implement.  Assuming I can successfully write to file I will later want to read from file.

Comment: This JavaScript is running in a browser, yes? To store the data on the server you do indeed need to make a HTTP request to your server - using AJAX would be a sensible choice (N.B. jquery is not an alternative choice, although it does provide a different syntax for using AJAX functionality).  Then at the server-side you need some code running (e.g. written using PHP, ASP.NET, NodeJS, or anything else you choose and is supported on your host) which can accept the data, and write it to a file. This is basic web application architecture, essentially.

Comment: P.S. You can't write the file to the server using Javascript because the Javascript runs in the site user's browser, on the user's machine. It is not located on the server, and has no direct access to it. (Nor does it have access to the filesystem on the machine where it's running). Instead the browser and the server communicate with each other using HTTP requests.

Comment: Of course another alternative to this is to write some server-side code which makes the request to Strava directly, retrieves the data, which is then already on the server, and saves it to the disk. You could then have a simple web page which allows you to trigger that operation (again, using a HTTP request from your browser)

Comment: Thank you for the comment ADyson.  Do you know where, for example, I could find some information on setting this up with say PHP on the server side and AJAX in the JavaScript.  The JavaScript is running in a browser.  Thank you.

Comment: I would try google. You can find literally dozens of AJAX/PHP tutorials, previous SO questions, etc. Just type in "php ajax tutorial" or similar.

Comment: P.S. If you used JavaScript to retrieve data from an API on a remote server...then that was also an AJAX request. So unless Strava provided you with a JS code library which abstracts away the mechanics, then you possibly already know how to make an AJAX request.

Comment: When a user authorizes one to access their Strava data Strava sends back a code in the redirect URL that is then used to make further requests to Strava to get access and refresh tokens.  I have a user clicking on a link on a web page, they are re-directed to Strava, they give permission and Strava redirects them back to a page on my site.  I extract the code from the URL using JavaScript, I make another request to Strava using JavaScript and I get an access and a refresh token back in a promise.  I need to store that information.

Comment: Yes I did make an AJAX request using "fetch".  Strava deals with the request.  Trouble is I don't know how to make requests and deal with them on my own server.  Thanks again for your response.  I will look for a php / ajax tutorial.

Comment: well the way you _make_ requests using fetch() is going to be basically the same structure. And how you make a PHP script read values that are input from a HTTP request is very well documented - it's one of PHP's most common tasks.

Comment: So your PHP looks for a key named `data` and you now don't have a key named `data` so … why do you expect anything to be written?

Comment: Hi Quentin.  I don't follow.  I have this:  xhttp.send(data);  Isn't that the data that I am passing to PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You would need another file on the back end, which would actually do the writing. I'll assume PHP. I'd recommend base64 encoding the data, and storing it encoded to save time.

Javascript:

```
if (window.XMLHTTPRequest) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHTTPRequest();
} else {
    var xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        //Process output, get result text with this.responseText, decode base64, and parse JSON
        alert(JSON.parse(window.atob(this.responseText)));
    }
}
xhttp.open("POST", "file-load.php?key=" + window.btoa(JSON.stringify(value)), true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhttp.send();
```

PHP:

```php
<?php
$key = $_POST['key'];
file_put_contents("storage.txt", $key); //Set file contents
```

Or, if you want to append it:

```php
<?php
$key = $_POST['key'];
$current = file_get_contents("storage.txt");
file_put_contents("storage.txt", $current . "\n" . $key);
```

To read the file, just use the same setup as before for javascript, but instead of `file-load.php`, use `file-read.php`:

```php
echo file_get_contents("storage.txt");
```

Use the `onreadystatechange` to read the output.

Comment: Thank you Redwolf Programs.  I was updating my question with progress made to date while you were answering.  I have taken a very similar approach to your suggestion.  It seems  you are passing the data to be written in a variable called "key".  The data I want to pass is a relatively large "nested" object.  Will I be able to pass that much data using key? I have tried FormData and hit the problems described in my edited question.  Thanks.

Comment: @AdrianJG Sounds like post would be better. Might be a good idea to convert the data to JSON before storing.

Comment: Thanks Redwolf Programs.  According to information here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send  one can only use the following with XMLHttpRequest.send: - Blob, BufferSource, FormData, URLSearchParams, ReadableStream or USVString.  I have searched around and it seems FormData is what most people use.  It seems I can't use JSON.  I believe I start with JSON before converting to FormData.

Comment: @AdrianJG Oh, forgot about that. Yeah, I'm used to get requests.